# angular-ui collaspe css animation issue with bootstrap panel

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've created a demo in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3pPjoCvni983Qtm86aWT?p=preview)
, which I use angular-ui [`collaspe`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) to work on bootstrap [panel](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels),
but it seems the ui animation not work well, when I click the title bar to collaspe, the panel-body will animate to its default padding 15px, then disappear immediately. And if I remove the padding of panel-body, the animation looks smoothly. So how can I remain the padding and fix the animation issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your `panel-body` inside another tag with `panel-collapse` class, like this:

```
<div class="panel-collapse" collapse="collaspe1">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="group-item" ng-repeat="group in recommendedGroups">
            <span>{{group.name}}</span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See updated [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cCZ1DcLb6OrHEgFXRyLJ?p=preview). I got this clue from markup for [Accordion](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion).

Comment: hei, I found a better way, just set panel-body padding to 0, and append a div in panel-body, set padding to 15px, then it fix

Comment: Well, my solution doesn't require any style changes, but see for yourself, what do you think is better.